# encryption class and List<T>

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let's say we have a data object, `Patient`, and we are binding a `List<Patient>` to a UI widget.

```
public class Patient
{
    public Patient(){}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MedicalNotes {get;set;}
}
```

We want to *encrypt* the contents of the `MedicalNotes` property before writing the record to the database (assume we are a small company and cannot afford the license fee of the SQL database that offers the transparent encryption feature) and *decrypt* the column's contents before it gets bound to the UI widget.

Do we instantiate a singleton **Crypto** class and feed a reference to it to the `Patient` constructor, so that each Patient object in the List can invoke the encryption object's methods?

Or does the Crypto instance stay outside the `Patient` object and mediate between the Database IO class and the `List<Patient>`

Comment: IMO, the `Patient` class shouldn't be responsible for encrypting itself or saving itself to the database.  It should represent a *patient*.

Comment: @Amy: I tend to agree with you on this.

Comment: How do you store your model in the database? Some ORM? Plain old SQL? XML Serialization?

Comment: And there is no need for *any* singleton class, being it crypto or otherwise!

Comment: @dymanoid:  the Patient object's properties are mapped to the `SqlParameters` collection of a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: From SQL Server 2016 SP1 onwards, Always Encrypted is available in all editions of SQL Server.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto: I thought the [design-patterns] tag was for such discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would separate it into 3 layers, your model layer does not care about the ciphering process and neither does your database. Those responsibilities have to be taken to another party:

**Model layer:**

```
public class Patient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MedicalNotes { get; set; }
}
```

**Database layer:**

```
public static class PatientDb
{
    public static void SavePatient(Patient patient)
    {
        //whatever happens here, you didn't post this
    }
}
```

**Intermediate layer:**

```
public class PatientHelpers
{
    public void SavePatient(Patient unencryptedPatient)
    {
        var encrypted = Crypto.EncryptPatient(unencryptedPatient);
        PatientDb.SavePatient(encrypted);
    }
}

public static class Crypto
{
    public Patient EncryptPatient(Patient patient)
    {
        //whatever happens here, you didn't post this
        return patient;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this separation of concerns. When the SelectCommand returns a DataTable, and each row is mapped to a `Patient` object, any encrypted column is decrypted before being assigned to the corresponding Patient property.

Answer (score 1):

You said your database layer needs this added security. So I guess it belongs into that layer. Encrypt before you save, decrypt after you load.